# Firebase profileChangeRequest not being called

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdk

I am attempting to do a profileChangeRequest for the displayName variable after my Facebook users login and exchange a Facebook token for a Firebase one, but when I go to display the displayName, it doesn't change.  In the example below, the display name prints out the Facebook user's name, but not "Hometown" (just an example).  An ideas as to why the profileChangeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion doesn't seem to be working? My code is below

Thanks,

Jacob

Code:

```
var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
        {

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {

                    let coolMes: String! = String(error.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"]!)

                    let Alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Warning", message: coolMes!, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")

                    Alert.show()
                }

                else{

                    user?.profileChangeRequest().displayName = "Hometown"
                    user?.profileChangeRequest().commitChangesWithCompletion({error in

                        if let error = error{

                        }

                        else{
                            print(user?.displayName)  // this prints the actual display name, NOT hometown, as expected

                            let CreateView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController") as! UITabBarController
                            self.presentViewController(CreateView, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                        })




                }
            }
```